# Причина обособления определения

Tags: пунктуация

В первом примере определение не обособлено, но обособлено во втором. Как вы думаете, это обязательное или авторское обособление?

(1) Евлашка посмотрел на избушку, на меня, на теплое небо в облачках и тихо засмеялся.

(2) Евлашка посмотрел на избушку, на меня, на теплое небо, всё в облачках, и тихо засмеялся.

Answer (score 2):

Евлашка посмотрел на избушку, на меня, на теплое небо, всё в облачках, и тихо засмеялся.- несогласованное определение обособлено в соответствии с правилом: несоглас. определение, выраженное косвенными падежами существительных, обособляется для выделения какого-либо признака или для усиления выражаемого ими значения.

В первом примере, у Ф.Гладкова,нет такого усиления или выделения.Всё перечисленное было одинаково близко Евлашке. Преобразованное предложение слегка меняет смысл: получается, что ему нравится всё, и даже небо, которое ВСЁ в облачках. Это уже оборот, не просто определение, выраженное одиночным сущ. с предлогом, поэтому обособление обязательно - оборот усиливает качество признака предмета.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что обособление обязательно, но можно ли обособить    определение не по семантике, а по по формальному признаку, а именно: несогласованное определение находится НА РАССТОЯНИИ от определяемого слова (их разделяет местоимение "весь"), а это признак обязательного обособления.

Comment: Такое объяснение неверно: ВСЁ входит в  распространённое определение(небо какое?-всё в облачках), поэтому определение не на расстоянии, а прямо следом за определяемым существительным. Одиночное НЕСОГЛАСОВАННОЕ  определение в постпозиции обособляется реже, только когда автор придаёт ему особое значение в предложении, а распространённое - это уже оборот, оно всегда усиливает и выделяет, потому и обособляется.

Comment: Вообще-то такое объяснение я встречала в учебном пособии (только не помню в каком), поэтому я не уверена, что "объяснение неверно". Обратите внимание на то, что НЕОБОСОБЛЕННОЕ несогласованное определение всегда НАЧИНАЕТСЯ С ПАДЕЖНОЙ ФОРМЫ, то есть впереди нет никаких слов. Или я ошибаюсь, и вы может привести такие примеры?

Comment: Вера, Вы меня не слышите:Небо, всё в облачках - определение "всё в облачках", а не "в облачках". А "всё" тогда что? ещё одно определение? Нет, "всё в облачках"-одно распространённое определение, и оно идёт сразу за определяемым словом. Ни в каком учебном пособии оборот не разбирается как сумма отдельных членов предложения, слов-да, а членов предложения - нет.

Comment: Несогласованное определение может быть одиночным, а может иметь зависимые слова, например: "Холоп с откинутыми НАЗАД  рукавами разносил напитки и съестное". Но в любом случае сразу после определяемого слова стоит именно падежная форма, но не зависимые слова, входящие в оборот.